# YouTubeAPI searchResult wrong

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, php-7, youtube-data-api

This is my API request with a randmon YT Channel:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&channelId=UCqwoHjwau6Js8wOq6LSmCxQ&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50

"totalResults": 3889

But there are only 9 pages with maxResults=50 (instead of 78 pages!). Many videos are not in the list...for example this one:

nnw6VP1VvLw

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `search` query has a call cap ( as well as a high quota count ). If you are wanting to list all videos from a selected channel, then use the `PlayListItems` instead.

Still has a max of 50 per call, but you can get all if you use `nextPageToken` and loop.

Comment: Channel:list     --> set   forUsername= xyz     get    "uploads": "xyz_Pl_Id"   PlaylistItem:list --> set "playlistId": "xyz_Pl_Id"  get all videos ever uploaded by this channel